# Databricks pyspark IPython.core.display.HTML error in eli5 output

Tags: python, html, pyspark, xgboost, databricks

XGBoost using eli5 for showing prediction prints results in HTML format, which is not working in pyspark in Databricks.

And `displayHTML(file_name)` is giving error:

> Py4JException: An exception was raised by the Python Proxy. Return Message: x

I have installed ipython library too.
Even for this simple query its giving error.

```
from IPython.display import display, HTML
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML

display(HTML('<h1>Hello, world!</h1>'))
print("Here's a link:")
display(HTML("<a href='http://www.google.com' target='_blank'>www.google.com</a>"))
print("some more printed text ...")
display(HTML('<p>Paragraph text here ...</p>'))
```

The Output/Error which I'm getting is:

```
<IPython.core.display.HTML at 0x7f63e0c5d5f8>
Here's a link:
<IPython.core.display.HTML at 0x7f6408fbe358>
some more printed text ...
<IPython.core.display.HTML at 0x7f6408fbe358>
```

Comment: @M.J any suggestions?

Comment: No sorry, i investigate but not found answer...